# Is it possible to use strikethrough (<s>, <strike>, <del>) in Trello?

Tags: trello, markdown

Trello accepts Markdown in card descriptions and it even helpfully links to the [Markdown syntax](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax) page.

That page mentions that *"for any markup that is not covered by Markdown’s syntax, you simply use HTML itself"*.

However, using `<del>` for example to strike through text does not result in satisfactory output. Neither does using some other HTML tags like `<strong>` or `<em>`.

Admittedly, `<strong>` or `<em>` really don't have to work because Markdown supports **bold** and *italic* formatting, however Markdown unfortunately lacks in `<del>` department, and probably in others too.

Is there a way to show that a text previously existed but now does not, in Trello, if strikethrough is not available?

Comment: This is more a direct feature request to Trello than a question about how to use it

Comment: @EightDaysofMalaise, since I didn't find information about this problem anywhere else, I thought of posting it here to get a definitive answer - maybe I'm the one doing something wrong. I admit, it grew into a bug/feature request the way I worded it at the end. The existence of 'features' and 'wish-list' tags confused me further into thinking this was OK (I now see what 'wish-list' tag is for).
Should I remove it or just rephrase it (because I do see questions in the line of "is it possible" when it's clear the feature isn't there)?

Comment: "Is it possible" entirely takes your question away from a feature request as other users can also say how or devs can come along later and say it's not possible.

Comment: @DomDelimar consider editing your question to point to [this answer](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/56851/48200) as `~~` now supported in Trello.

Answer (score 188, accepted):

While you still can't use tags (like `<del>`), in February 2014, Trello [added](https://trello.com/c/lzWiUQYd/1496-add-strikethrough) the ability to cross out text using `~~foo~~`.

Comment: This is actually the best answer and should be voted up.

Comment: Also works on Github: https://help.github.com/articles/github-flavored-markdown

Comment: not working in Github gist....

Answer (score 36):

Use double tildes to ~~strike~~ text in markdown!

Comment: This works in some implementations of markdown, but not in Trello and not here on Stack Exchange.

Comment: This now works on Trello =). @Goutte was just early.

Comment: this does not work for me... weird nope? but i've seen it on stackoverflow, so i reckon there is another typo?