# Strikethrough in card comment

Tags: trello

I'd like to strike through **a comment** (or part of comment) on a trello card.

How can I achieve that, markdown, HTML?

<s>Like this</s>

Comment: You used HTML in your example `<s>Like this</s>`.  The markdown equivalent is `~~Like this~~`: ~~Like this~~

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In February 2014, Trello [added](https://trello.com/c/lzWiUQYd/1496-add-strikethrough) the ability to cross out text using `~~foo~~`.

[image: strikethrough support]

Comment: Awesome, works in card descriptions, comments and checklist items!

Answer (score 2):

Not currently (just tried it).
See [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/24394/is-it-possible-to-use-strikethrough-s-strike-del-in-trello), one of the answers mentions possible future support.

Markdown in card comments is listed under ideas, see the [Trello dev board](https://trello.com/board/trello-development/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c).

UPDATE:

As per Daniel's answer: Since February 2014 strikethrough is officially supported in Trello using the following syntax: ~~strikethrough~~.